# Subscriber is running multiple times ,even if we unsuscribed it

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

file name :- brief-component.ts
I am calling drawer service like
`this.assignDrawerService.showDrawer(parameter);`

file name:-  drawer-service.ts

```
 private drawerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public drawer$: Observable<boolean> = this.drawerSubject.asObservable();

 public showDrawer(viewType:any) {
        this.drawerSubject.next(viewType);
        }
```

file name :- drawer-component.ts

Debugger hitting multiple times

```
this.assignDrawerService.drawer$.subscribe(viewType => {
      debugger
});
```

I am expecting subscriber should run once .
I tried takeUntil , unsuscribe , first

Comment: Can you extend your second snippet to show how/when you're subscribing?

Comment: @Pieterjan , I subscrive those code in constructor . i checked how much time constructor run , it ran once only.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a BehaviorSubject, which has an initial value (in your case "false"). That means it will fire at least once with the value "false" and then every time you call `this.drawerSubject.next(viewType);`

Use a normal Subject without an initial value.

Comment: public drawer$ = new Subject<boolean>(); I used like this , still having same issue

Comment: That should be correct. Have you tried debugging the showDrawer method? It will fire even if the value is the same. But then you would have to find out what is calling the method.

Comment: Also, how have you unsubscribed? You need to assign the subscription to a variable and then call unsubscribe on the variable.

Comment: I tried by adding debugger in showDrawer method , its running only once . And also i used unsubscribe like this.suscriptionUserNRole=this.assignDrawerService.destroy$.subscribe(viewType => {
      debugger  this.suscriptionUserNRole.unsubscribe(); }